# How to improve the performance of search filter in angular for a large list

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, search, ionic-framework

when typing in the search bar the mouse event pauses for a few seconds while typing until the data is loaded( it seems as though every click event triggers the data to load in the search) this happens for the first few typing using a search filter pipe) without a search pipe it is still slow . Please help thanks 
Please click on the link to view the stackblitz example:

https://ionic-6cbe9t.stackblitz.io

```
searchFilter(searchTerm){
  if(searchTerm != ''){
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  }

  if(!this.listFromArray){
    return Immutable.List();
 }

  if(!searchTerm){
    return this.listFromArray;
  }

  return  this.listFromArray.filter((address) => {
    return address.Company.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
        address.Phone.toString().includes(searchTerm) ||
        address.Street.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
        address.City.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)  ||
        address.Phone.includes(searchTerm);
  });
}
```

Comment: add a debounceTime in your Observable or add the condition to check if length is greater that 3 characters... (NOTE: It's hard try to help without know the code you're using)

Comment: Hi thanks i am using a simple search filter pipe. that filters an array of items. Then I add the filter to the *ngFor="let item of Items | filterItems: searchTerm".

Comment: <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" ></ion-searchbar>

Comment: I put how make a general search with debounceTime. I hope this help you. Anyway, perhafs you can improve if you add a new property "searchTerms" when you load the items

Answer (score 2):

How make a "debounceTime" search

Your component.html

```
  <input #search (keyup)="searchTerm.next(search.value)">
  <div *ngIf="results"> 
    <!--slice is optional-->
    <div *ngFor="let item of results |slice:0:10">
         {{item.descripcion}}
    </div>
   </div>
```

In your component.ts

```
  //We defined three variables,
  items:any[];  //our items
  results:any[];  //Our items filtered
  searchTerm = new Subject<string>();  //A subject 

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    //here we can put others conditions to term
    //like term.lenght>3, e.g.
    if (!term)
      return of(null);  //Notice we return an observable -using Observable.of
    term=term.toUpperCase();
    return of(     //Idem before. If we're ask about an observable
                   //Like httpClient.get, we not need "of" 
       this.items.filter(a=>a.searchProperty.indexOf(term)>=0)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //we subscribe to get the items
    this.http.get("assets/items.json").subscribe((res:any[])=>{
         //we can do this.items=res ...
         //this.items=res;
         //...but better make a map and create a property "searchProperty"
         //so, our filtered can be over this property. notice
         //the map is executed only one time
         this.items=res.map(x=>{
           return {
                   ...x,
                   searchProperty:x.descriptcion.toUpperCase()
                         +x.texto.toUpperCase()
                         +x.comment.toUpperCase()
                   }
          });
         //then, we subscribe to "this.search"
        this.search(this.searchTerm)
          .subscribe(results => {
             this.results = results;   
        });
    });
}
```

NOTE: The code is largely inspired from https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/

Comment: thanks much appreciated. Is there a way to do this using a pipe ? This was it can be a reusable search

Comment: I dont want to make a call to the api every time I want a search. I would like the list to be displayed when the component load and filter the list when the user type

Comment: The code don't call to the api every time, just in a ngOnInit one time. I don't know how "translate in a pipe", but must be easy create a custom component that received as @Input the data. The "key" of the code is convert in Observable the "change" of the search, don't call to a function each time the seach change

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use a component service class and bind the searchTerm to search custom input<search-component [search]=“searchTerm”></search-component>   . Why did the code scallef the search() method inside of the api subscription that is confusing . I have an available list view displayed from the api, and I stored that array results inside an collection[] = apiResults;  this array iterates over an ngFor array  to display to the user. The array list is what I will be filtering . How do I bind the search term to the custom input ?